# Any SMTP server can send mails to any other SMTP server?

Tags: python, authentication, networking, smtp

I am creating a Python program to send a confirmation email to users.

I want to send a message using the SMTP protocol. I have not deep knowledge of network and email. So I searched on Google and here, I found many questions and answers about SMTP.

I've read "[Sending email from SMTP server without the need to enter password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484492/sending-email-from-smtp-server-without-the-need-to-enter-password)". And it says that an SMTP server at localhost which usually doesn't require any credentials. If so, can that SMTP server send mails to outside without any restriction?

If spam have SMTP server-like feature, can that spam send emails without any restriction? What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: The problem here is that most ISPs block SMTP Traffic from Dynamic IP Adresses due to Spam Policy, that means you E-Mail delivery is not guaranteed.

You should design your program so, that you can use a external SMTP Server with Authentification.

Comment: I'm not clear still. Do you mean an internal SMTP server is useless for sending email to outside world?

Comment: Not 100% useless but nearly useless. Whats the problem with a SMTP Relay Server ?

Comment: @Marc there's no indication that the OP is sending emails from an end-user host with a dynamic IP address..

Comment: Thank you. I wrongly thought that I can send confirmation mails to my customers without registering to any email service. I'm now clear that I have to use a public email service.

Comment: @Alnitak With that ammount of knowledge, im really hoping he dosnt run a server...
regardless, the best way is to use a relay server to send mail. so you dont have to worry about abuse and other stuff

Comment: @Pho it depends entirely on the environment in which your Python application service is running.    If it's on a dedicated server in a data center with static public IP addresses, you could well be fine.   OTOH, some network providers have dubious reputations of their own that might cause you issues...

Comment: In practise the question is actually off topic for here anyway.   The code to use a relay or to use a local SMTP server would be more or less identical, and this is a programming site, not one for system architecture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly programming related, but is instead seeking systems architecture advice.

Comment: But, a friend of mine said that he received a mail from my locally-installed GitLab. What about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically any SMTP server can contact any other SMTP server on Internet and try to send a message, but every normally configured SMTP server will not accept a message from Internet unless it is addressed to its local recipients. The reason is that SMTP servers must not relay email unless it comes from a trusted source. That is an important anti-spam measure.

There is nothing technical that will prevent you from sending spam. But if it happens and somebody complains, your admin or your provider will take steps to stop it. Because if not, the whole site will be added to some spammers blacklist.